# Android não encontra a variável local, porem não existe

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá estou rodando um debug neste codigo e no final ele da esta mensagem no debug.

Cannot find local variable 'NomeLocal'

Porem ja procurei em todo o meu código e não acho esta variável não sei o que fazer esta pensando em refazer o código não sei se pode ser um lixo que esteja em algum arquivo.

Mas antes disto queria saber se vcs ja tiveram algo parecido.

```
public class CriarPrato extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner LocalRestaurante;
private Spinner NomeRestaurante;
private EditText NomePrato;
private EditText PrecoPrato;
private Button GerarPrato;
private String IDrestaurante;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_criar_prato);

    LocalRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinerLocalPrato);
    NomeRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato);
    NomePrato = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomePrato);
    PrecoPrato = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrecoPrato);
    GerarPrato = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrato);

    Query queryPrato = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").orderByChild("localRestaurante");

    queryPrato.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> localRest = new ArrayList<String>();
            final List<String> NomeRestauranteList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Restaurante restaurante = data.getValue(Restaurante.class);
                localRest.add(restaurante.getLocalRestaurante().toString());
                NomeRestauranteList.add(restaurante.getNome().toString());
            }

            LocalRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinerLocalPrato);
            ArrayAdapter<String> areas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, localRest);
            areas.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
            LocalRestaurante.setAdapter(areas);

            NomeRestaurante = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato);
            ArrayAdapter<String> NomeRestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, NomeRestauranteList);
            NomeRestAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
            NomeRestaurante.setAdapter(NomeRestAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    GerarPrato.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Prato prato = new Prato();
            String NomeSelcRestaurante= NomeRestaurante.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Query queryPrato2 = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Restaurante").orderByChild("nome").equalTo(NomeSelcRestaurante);
            queryPrato2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    IDrestaurante = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            prato.setNomePrato(NomePrato.getText().toString());
            prato.setPrecoPrato("R$"+ PrecoPrato.getText().toString());
            prato.setID(IDrestaurante);
            prato.Salvar(IDrestaurante);
        }
    });


}
```

}

file.xml

```
TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Favor selecionar o local do restaurante."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinerLocalPrato"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextNomePrato"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Favor selecionar o restaurante."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNomePrato"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPrecoPrato"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Nome do Prato"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,LabelFor,MissingConstraints"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPrecoPrato"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ButtonCriarPrato"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="Preço"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextNomePrato"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/editTextNomePrato"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,LabelFor,MissingConstraints,UnknownId"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonPrato"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editTextNomePrato" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerNomeRestaurantePrato"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editTextNomePrato"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="269dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPrato"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sugiro que de um `CONTROL+SHIFT+F` e faça uma busca completa por esta variável, caso encontre-a remova e seu projeto irá compilar. Caso não aja a variável em questão no seu projeto, vá em `Build -> Clean Project` e depois vá em `Build -> Rebuild Project` para reconstruir todo o seu projeto novamente.

Comment: valeu deu certo !!! :)

Comment: Deu um Rebuild Project

Comment: Boa =) VictorT...